# Pre-geodesic question

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> **Definition:** Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional real manifold and $\nabla$ be a linear connection on $M$. A smooth curve $\gamma:(-\xi,\xi)\to M$ is called a **pre-geodesic** if there exists a function $\lambda:I\to \mathbb R$ such that $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'=\lambda \gamma'$.

It is easy to show that: *if there exist a diffeomorphism $h:J\to I$ such that $\bar\gamma=\gamma\circ h$ is a geodesic, then $\gamma$ is a pre-geodesic*. In fact, if $\gamma^ 1,\ldots,\gamma^n$ is the coordinates of $\gamma$ of some local chart, the condition $\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\bar\gamma'=0$ is equivalent to:
$$\frac{d^2\gamma^\mu}{dt^2}_{|h(s)}+\Gamma_{\nu\sigma}^\mu\big(\bar \gamma(s)\big)\frac{d\gamma^\nu}{dt}_{|h(s)}\frac{d\gamma^\sigma}{dt}_{|h(s)}=-\frac{h^{\prime\prime}(s)}{h'(s)^2}\frac{d\gamma^\mu}{dt}_{|h(s)}$$

> **Question:** How can I prove the converse?: *if $\gamma$ is a pre-geodesic, then there exists a diffeomorphism $h:J\to I$ such that $\gamma\circ h$ is a geodesic.*

**Idea:** For any real function $\lambda$ there exists a diffeomorphism $h$ such that $(h')^2+\lambda h^{\prime\prime}=0$ ?

Comment: What direction is the converse? Could you be more clear on exactly what you're trying to prove, what you have been able to prove, and where you're stuck on the "converse"?